# Using SELECT against a linked server database with ApplicationIntent=ReadOnly turned on

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I am using SQL Server 2014 and trying to do a SELECT through a linked SQL server against a database table on another server (maintained by a different team), which is also on SQL Server 2014 or higher.

- The remote database requires `ApplicationIntent=ReadOnly` to connect
- I have successfully created a LINKED server against the remote database
- I wish to create a SQL job on my side, which will pull over the content of a table on that database, to a staging table on my side
- However, I am not even able to do a `SELECT * FROM [RemoteServer].[RemoteDatabase].[RemoteTable]` from my SQL Server instance
- The error message I get is

  > The OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server [RemoteServer] does not contain the table [RemoteDatabase].[RemoteTable]. The table either does not exist or the current user does not have permissions on that table.
- I can do `SELECT * FROM [RemoteDatabase].[RemoteTable]` just fine if I connect to the remote server's SQL Server instance directly, so it is not an issue with the query or that the table does not exist. I believe it is because of the `ApplicationIntent=ReadOnly`

My question is: Is there a way I can do get my linked server to work, to run the remote query?

Comment: The credentials that the SQL Agent job run under is the source of your problem.  The only case where this statement would not be true is if you are actually going to the trouble of signing into SSMS with the same credentials that SQL Agent is configured to use, when you issue your working `SELECT` against the linked server.  But I bet you are using a different account, either your windows credentials or a SQL account different from what SQL Agent is using.

Comment: Thanks David and sorry for the late response, since I was out of town. I took a look and it appears that I am running SQL Server agent under  my same credentials (this is on my development box) as the one which I used to connect through SSMS.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM [RemoteServer].[RemoteDatabase].dbo.[RemoteTable]
```

Make sure to qualify the remote table with `dbo`.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32010107)